# Downgrade hibernate version

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I have the following configuration based on Hibernate 4.1.7.Final

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
        p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
        p:packagesToScan="com.ucmas.cms.entity" p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

However, now I would like to achieve the same result with hibernate 3.6.0.Final. May I know what the configuration should look like ? I tried to change the org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean to org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean, but it gives "no setter found for property" packagesToScan. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` instead of `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean`.

In spring-hibernate3 annotations are not supported using the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` factory, for annotation support they have `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`, but in hibernate4 support they have enabled it by default.

And need to use `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager` transaction manager

Comment: how about the transactionManager ? which class should it refer too ?

Comment: TransactionManager: `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager`